# Upper Type Bounds with Parameter

Tags: scala

Is it possible in Scala to define an Upper Type Bounds with parameter?
for example:

```scala
abstract class AbstractWorker[Request <: AbstractCommand, Response <: AbstractCommand] {
  protected def handleRequest
  def onMessage(msg: AbstractCommand): Behavior[AbstractCommand] = msg match {
    case Request(replyTo) => 
      val res = handleRequest
      replayTo ! res
 }

object AbstractWorker {
  trait AbstractCommand
}
```

As you can see, I want to make sure that the `replayTo` exists on `Request` subtype.

The above example does not compile because `replayTo` does not exists.

**Note**: I cannot add this to `AbstractCommand`.

Also, how can I make the concrete class which extends `AbstractWorker` a requirement to explicit pass `Request` and `Response`? since the IDE not checking if its an error, but its fails on compile time.

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to use inheritance for that, rather a typeclass

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using `AbstractCommand` everywhere to hardcode `ActorRef` type (which is a bad idea).

If `AbstractCommand` has a field `val replyTo`, then you can just write:

```
case ac: AbstractCommand =>
  val replyTo = ac.replyTo
```

If you want to handle it with pattern matching, you can still do

```
trait AbstractCommand {
  val replyTo: ActorRef[AbstractCommand]
}
object AbstractCommand {
  def unapply(ac: AbstractCommand): Some[ActorRef[AbstractCommand]] =
    Some(ac.replyTo)
}
```

and then

```
case AbstractCommand(replyTo) =>
```

To fix hardcoded type add `[Response]` in the class and method signatures above and replace `ActorRef[AbstractCommand]` with `ActorRef[Response]`.

But you can also use a typeclass if you want your pattern match code to look exactly as you presented:

```
// typeclass + extractor at once
trait ReplyToExtractor[Request, Response] {
  // to have nice SAM semantics
  def extract(req: Request): ActorRef[Response]

  def unapply(req: Request): Some[ActorRef[Response]] = Some(extract(req))
}
```

```
abstract class AbstractWorker[Request, Response](
  implicit val Request: ReplyToExtractor[Request, Response]
) {

  protected def handleRequest: Response

  def onMessage(msg: AbstractCommand): Behavior[AbstractCommand] = msg match {
    case Request(replyTo) => 
      val res = handleRequest
      replayTo ! res
  }
}
```

```
case class CommandA(replyTo: ActorRef[ResultA], otherargs)
object CommandA {
  implicit val extractor: ReplyToExtractor[CommandA, ResultA] = _.replyTo
}
```

This way there are no constraints about supertypes of `Request` and `Response`.